# How to use UIBezier Path For Making UIButton

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I have to make UIButton in Specify Shape.That Shape have to convert in UIButton How Can i do..plz Help..!!

[image]

Comment: Either have an image of that shape and use it as background image or draw the shape using bezier path in the drawRect of the button.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be to create the shape you want using a CAShapeLayer and add a touch detector to it that triggers an action.

If you're unfamiliar with CALayer and its many applications Ray Wenderlich has an excellent overview [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples).

Answer (score 0):

First of all **UIBezier Path** is not For Making UIButton it is for giving a shape for UIButton.

Second, if you want to give shape to your UIButton then Apple provided all detail regarding [BezierPaths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) in their document.

As ican understand you need to shape button like Curve shape then on Apples document provided method here .

> #define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((pi * degrees)/ 180)
>
> ```
> - (UIBezierPath *)createArcPath
> {
>    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150)
>                            radius:75
>                            startAngle:0
>                            endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(135)
>                            clockwise:YES];
>    return aPath;
> }
> ```

**[image]**

There are two mainly curve provided by apple and inbuilt method in beizear path.

**[image]**

You need to use **Quadratic curve** to shape your UIButton.

Please check this link.
[addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:)

and Use inbuilt method and change **endpoint** and **controlpoint** According to your shape.

[image]

[image]

Note:- You need to change the point according to your Requirement.